# Html child element height by max-height parent wrapper

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have row line with `max-height: 300px`.

In documantation
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#min-max-heights
I read that: "max-height on a child, it is a percentage of the parent's actual height".
Okey lets parent has unknown height , but his height cant be more than setted max-height, right?

But why is child div is overflow parent?  I try add min-h-0 to child's div nothing has changed

```
<div class="flex items-start max-h-[300px]">
    <div class="max-h-full"><img src="veryBigImage"/></div>
    <div class="max-h-full"><video src="veryBigVideo"/></div>
</div>
```

[image]

p.s. (I'm not considering the correctness of the display of internal elements here, there can be a lot of elements in the wrappers, I don't control them.)

**Update.**

1,2 - how should work by documentation. Yes, incorrect image cut\display but wrapper cant overflow parrent with min-height:0 flex +(overflow: hidden *optional)

3 - how work now , wrapper overflow parrent
[image]

Sandbox:
https://play.tailwindcss.com/bvfy0kF5Nz

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you're correct about `max-height`, but the real problem is your `img` and `video`.

They are controlled by the actual size of the resource (like image, etc.), not by HTML

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp

> Images are not technically inserted into a web page; images are linked to web pages. The  tag creates a holding space for the referenced image.

If you want to overcome this problem, you need to set `width` or `height` properly for `img` or `video` (by CSS or inline attributes) that would help HTML understand your expected size.

Comment: That is, html cant how to make a line with the maximum specified height into which the content will be stuffed like in a jar?

Comment: and your statement does not contradict in any way that my example with (parent - child max-height  hight) is built according to all the rules given by me with a link to the documentation

Comment: images and videos are external resources, and they come after HTML loaded which means HTML cannot predict the size if we don't give a proper size instruction to `img` and `video` tags

Comment: Let the resources themselves be displayed incorrectly , but according to the documentation , they cannot change the size of the wrapper more than specified in the parent element

Comment: You can try to make 1 with an image and 1 without an image for comparison. Even though you can try to put multi-level div too. HTML tags do follow the rule of `max-height` (like you mentioned) because it's already painted when HTML is loaded, but images are loaded separately and came later after HTML loaded.

Comment: Yes, let it be image displayed incorrectly as cut, no difference. But the wrapper of this picture according to the documentation cannot exceed the parent with the options min-height:0 +flex if parent have max-height . shuld be as red rectangle,  but now it goes far down 
 https://i.ibb.co/86Sx8rh/cat.png  OR as this if not overflow https://i.ibb.co/G9mTJsT/cat2.png but rectangle cant be more parrent

Comment: your rectangle is HTML's element and it's painted far earlier than your image (if you inspect your network and set your network to 3G, you will see that your image come late https://helpdeskgeek.com/networking/simulate-slow-internet-connection-testing/). If you don't allow that overflow happens, you need to set CSS to the parent element like `overflow: hidden` or `overflow: auto` (the default one is `visible`)

Comment: Added a description. I tried your method with slow internet, I come to option 3. In the documentation, I have to come to 1 or 2 options.  I'm waiting for your code that will lead me to option 1/2. :)

Comment: Could you show me your CSS in option 3? And you want my code to solve option 1 and 2?

Comment: https://play.tailwindcss.com/bvfy0kF5Nz  yes i want option 2

Comment: The problem is you set `max-h-full` (height: 100%) of div but in this case, div does not have any height reference and it used the actual size of the image, so that's why you see the border get applied with the image size. `"max-height on a child, it is a percentage of the parent's actual height"`(max-height on child is image, so 100% height on parent div will be image size).By the way, https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#min-max-heights, they also mentioned max-height applied to `all elements but non-replaced inline elements, table columns, and column groups` (inline elements like `img`)

Comment: 1) max-h-full is max-height:100% ;  2)  parent for wrapper is div with rule (max-height 300px)  "max-height on a child"  = "it is a percentage of the parent's actual height"  TAKE any 0px 2px 200px 300px ! how its value can be increase max-height parent if we set min-height:0; 3)  Is it impossible to come to option 2 ?

Comment: You can try to replace `<img>` with `<div>Test</div>`, you will understand how `max-height on a child, it is a percentage of the parent's actual height` works.

Comment: @padavan does it not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

after 2 days I found a solution!!! Without add height and nothing set for "img and video"

@nick-vu thanks for trying

https://play.tailwindcss.com/mTcsccgElW

```
  <div class="flex flex-col max-h-[300px] bg-purple-500 grow">
    <div class="flex-grow flex h-0 bg-orange-200">
      <div class="min-h-0 border-[5px] border-red-700">
        <img class="max-h-full" src="https://wallpapershome.ru/images/pages/pic_v/14572.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image]

Comment: `If  you want to overcome this problem, you need to set width or height properly for img or video (by CSS or inline attributes) that would help HTML understand your expected size.` I gave you the answer earlier tho

Comment: Perhaps, I misunderstood your question. By the way, I'm glad you're able to achieve your goal :D